# Raw capture capabilities (CAP_NET_RAW, CAP_NET_ADMIN) not working outside /usr/bin and friends for packet capture program using libpcap

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wireshark, libpcap, linux-capabilities

***TL;DR:* Why are `cap_net_raw`, `cap_net_admin` capabilities only working in `/usr/bin` (or `/usr/sbin`), but not other places? Can this be configured someplace?**

I'm having problems assigning capabilities to my C program utilizing libpcap in Ubuntu 14.04. Even after assigning capabilities using `setcap(8)` and checking it using `getcap(8)`, I still get a permission error. It seems capabilities only work for executables in `\usr\bin` and friends.

My program `test.c` looks as follows:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pcap.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("Specify interface \n");
        return -1;
    }
    char errbuf[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];
    struct pcap* pcap = pcap_open_live(argv[1], BUFSIZ, 1, 0, errbuf);
    if (pcap == NULL) {
        printf("%s\n", errbuf);
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and is compiled with

```
gcc test.c -lpcap
```

generating `a.out` executable. I set capabilities:

```
sudo setcap cap_net_raw,cap_net_admin=eip ./a.out
```

And check to see that it looks right:

```
getcap a.out
```

which gives me

```
a.out = cap_net_admin,cap_net_raw+eip
```

Running `a.out` gives me:

```
./a.out eth0
eth0: You don't have permission to capture on that device (socket: Operation not permitted)
```

Running with `sudo` works as expected (program prints nothing and exits).

Here's the interesting part: If I move `a.out` to `/usr/bin` (and reapply the capabilities), it works. Vice versa: taking the capability-enabled `/usr/bin/dumpcap` from `wireshark` (which works fine for users in the `wireshark` group) and moving it *out* of `/usr/bin`, say to my home dir, reapplying the same capabilities, it *doesn't* work. Moving it back, it works.

SO: Why are these capabilities only working in `/usr/bin` (and `/usr/sbin`), but not other places? Can this be configured someplace?

Comment: The test prog (with the capabilities as above) works AOK on my pretty much out of the box Fedora-21. Shot in the dark: Security permissions related ? (I know nothing specifically related to Ubuntu but I gather there's something called AppArmor on Ubuntu which might be similar to SELinux on Fedora).

Comment: You're probably right, @willyo ... I did try to disable AppArmor and unloading profiles (to no avail), but didn't go much further

Answer (score 15):

This might be because your home directory is mounted with `nosuid`, which seems to prevent capabilities working. Ubuntu encrypts the home directory, and mounts that with ecryptfs as nosuid.

Binaries with capabilities work for me in `/usr/`, and `/home/`, but not my home directory.

The only reference I could find to `nosuid` defeating capabilities is this link: http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/linux/kernel/1860853#1860853.  I would love to find an authoritative source.

Comment: this should get many more upvotes since I also stumbled across this problem, scratching my head for a long time. I did not find this answer since the capability I was searching for was `CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE` which should be mentioned here as well in hopes of more people finding this.

Comment: You can use `getpcaps $(pidof ./a.out)` to list the capabilities of the running process. Try `sudo mount -o remount,suid /home` and check whether it works then.

Comment: Of note: this problem helped me solve an issue with python and bluetooth, resulting in the exception: `_bluetooth.error: (1, 'Operation not permitted')`. I am using the beacontools package with python3.6, and it relies on capabilities. Since many people develop in their home directory, this could be an issue for other packages as well.

Comment: Unfortunately it seems this problem won't be fixed anytime soon. Check https://bugs.launchpad.net/ecryptfs/+bug/1147348

Comment: Massive thumbs-up from here! Also wasted almost a week trying to fight this issue, in vain. None of the Linux-capabilities-howtos/-intros I've come across with mention this either. It's all just `ping`-this, `ping`-that.